# Android Jetpack Compose states from external class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am starting to learn Compose in Android and regarding `states` for me is clear how to manage them for "internal" states defining local variables in the Composable functions with `remember` and `mutableStateOf`. With "internal" I mean for instance if a checkbox is checked or a DropDown item is expanded or even the selected item index.

The problem comes when I want to dynamically change the representation of the composable elements in the UI according to the values from an external class. I will give you an example: I have implemented the `MainService` class that manages a foreground service (start, stop, binding, etc.):

```
class ManageService (val mContext: Context){
    fun start(){ // Starts the service }
    fun bind(){ // Binds to the service }
    fun stop(){ // Stops the service }
    fun plyMedia(){ // If bound, play media }
    fun isStarted() : Boolean{ // Returns if service is started }
    fun isBound() : Boolean{ // Returns if service is bound }
}
```

Now I want to call the methods from my `ManageService` class (start service, stop service, etc.) from the UI (buttons) and update the UI according to the status of the service (if the service is started, stopped, bound, etc.). I could think of of initializing my `MainService` class from the `ComponentActivity()` class and pass the class to each composable function like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    var mManageService: ManageService = ManageService(this)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainScreen(mManageService)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CreateButton(text:String, onClick: ()-> Unit){
    Button(
        onClick = onClick
    ){
        Text(text = text)
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(service:ManageService){
    Column (modifier = Modifier.background(color)){
        Text("Hello")
    if(service.isStarted()){
        Text("Service started")
    }
    else {
        Text("Service not started")
    }
        Row (modifier=Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
            CreateButton("Stop service") { service.stop() }
            CreateButton("Start service") { service.start() }
            CreateButton("Play media") { service.playMedia() // After binding }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am afraid this is not the right way to work with Compose.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When using states from another class inside of your views, you have to observe the state to alter the UI accordingly. Currently your screen will not get notified when your service is being started. To observe these changes you have to declare a state variable in your `ManageService` class. You can do this as follow:

```
val isStarted = mutableStateOf(false)
```

In your view it is then possible to use this state by just calling `manageService.isStarted`.

This approach is fine and works. However you could also use Kotlin Flow to manage your states. This keeps your Kotlin class clean and free of Jetpack Compose code.

This would look something like this

```
// ManageService
val isStarted = MutableStateFlow(false)

// UI - normally
val isStarted = manageService.isStarted.collectAsState()

// UI - lifecycle aware
val isStarted = manageService.isStarted.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

The last way of collection your state changes does also keep the lifecycle of your app in account. This is mostly used with viewModels. However to use this you also have to add a new dependency

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2")
}
```

However to learn more I can highly recommend to read the documentation on Managing states in Compose. These might be some useful links: [State and Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), [ViewModels and State in Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#0)

Added as an elaboration of my comment:
If you would like to return the state of the mediaPlayer from your service it is better to return the state value instead of a new state object. Otherwise you won't be able to observe the state changes.

```
// declaration of the state variable
val isPlayingState = mutableStateOf(false)

// returning the value of state variable
fun isPlaying() = isPlayingState.value
```

Additionally you have to update the isPlayingState whenever you start or stop your MediaPlayer. Doing so will give you the accurate representation of the actual state of the `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would start with the simple way, that is defining the property in my class as "val isStarted = mutableStateOf(false)" which will perfectly work to know if the srevice is started. Now my question is if instead of a property I could also define the method isPlaying() that would "return" a MutableStateOf(). I am asking that because my service starts a MediaPlayer, and my isPlaying() method should call "return mediaplayer.isPlaying()" method to be sure that the MediaPlayer is indeed playing the media.

Comment: If your isPlaying() method would return a new state object each time it is called the UI won't be able to subscribe to its changes. Because each time the entire object is changed instead of the state. It would be better to locate the MutableState inside of your Service. And then return it's value trough to isPlaying Method. I will update my answer with a code snippet.

Comment: This solution will work for the start/stop commands given to the MediaPlayer from my service (I could update the isPlayingState variable based on that), but what if the MediaPlayer is stopped by the OS?, the only way to be sure that the MediaPlayer is still playing an therefore have the UI updated is to attach somehow the state to a calll to mediaPlayer. isPlaying(), but I assume that this is not possible, right?

Comment: I do not have experience with the MediaPlayer itself, however there might be a callback function which you can use to see if the mediaPlayer is stopped. In this callback function you can then update the isStarted state.